# Creating a GIN index in Django

Tags: django, indexing

I have created a model in Django.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    features = TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

There are several possible ways to store the data in the `feature` field. Some examples below.

1. `feature1;feature2`
2. `feature1, feature2`
3. `feature1,feature2`

And so on. I need to create a GIN index for that field. I would probably do it in postgreSQL in the following way

```
CREATE INDEX features_search_idx ON "mymodel" USING gin (regexp_split_to_array("mymodel"."features", E'[,;\\s]+'));
```

Would it be possible to do the same thing by a migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- Create an empty migration: `python manage.py makemigration yourapp --empty -n pour_gin`
- Add a [`migrations.RunSQL()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation in the migration file.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # ...
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="""CREATE INDEX features_search_idx ON "mymodel" USING gin (regexp_split_to_array("mymodel"."features", E'[,;\\s]+'));""",
            reverse_sql=migrations.RunSQL.noop,  # TODO: replace me with DROP INDEX
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Is `DROP INDEX` essential?

Comment: If you want to be able to undo the migration at any point, it'd be nice to have.