# Size of a GIN index in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have created a model in Django.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    features = TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

There are several possible ways to store the data in the `feature` field. Some examples below.

1. `feature1;feature2`
2. `feature1, feature2`
3. `feature1,feature2`

And so on. I created a GIN index for that field using `migrations.RunSQL()` (thanks to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109727/creating-a-gin-index-in-django)). The postgreSQL command looks as follows

```
CREATE INDEX features_search_idx ON "mymodel" USING gin (regexp_split_to_array("mymodel"."features", '[,;\\s]+'));
```

Now I need to check the size of the created index in my database. I tried to do it with the following commands

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size("mymodel"."features_search_idx"));

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size("features_search_idx")) FROM "mymodel";
```

The latter one failed with `ERROR:  column "features_search_idx" does not exist` and the former one failed with `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "mymodel"`.

How can I check the index size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_indexes_size` takes an argument of type `regclass`, that is an object ID that is represented as a string that is the object name. So if you don't supply an object ID, you have to supply a *string* (single quotes) that is the name of the table:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size('mymodel.features_search_idx'));
```

Comment: Did you mean `'mymodel.features_search_idx#'`?

Comment: No, sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Ok, I understand. There is still an error: `ERROR:  schema "mymodel" does not exist`. Should I also add an information about the database before another dot?

Comment: Then you are connected to a different database.

Comment: I must check that then. Thank you!